# Strategies for providing packages as version control repositories

Tags: packages, texlive, revision-control, git

I'm working on experimental packages (say `my-package-1` and  `my-package-2`). Their changes are tracked thanks to a version control system (`git` in fact), the corresponding repositories being as follows:

```
./
├── doc
│   └── latex
│       └── my-package-⟨n⟩
│           ├── README
│           ├── README.md
│           └── my-package-⟨n⟩.pdf
├── source
│   └── latex
│       └── my-package-⟨n⟩
│           ├── my-package-⟨n⟩.dtx
│           └── my-package-⟨n⟩.ins
└── tex
    └── latex
        └── my-package
            └── my-package-⟨n⟩.sty
```

Some people are supposed to test these packages and, for convenience, I'd like to avoid them compilations of the `.ins` and .`dtx` files: they should be able to use these packages just by cloning in their `TEXMFHOME`¹ the corresponding `git` repositories:

```
git clone ssh://path/to/my-package-⟨n⟩.git
```

### Cloning repositories in `$TEXMFHOME/my-package-⟨n⟩/`: not a solution

Running these commands from `$TEXMFHOME/` directory clones the repositories, *not* into `TEXMFHOME`'s root, *but* into `$TEXMFHOME/my-package-⟨n⟩/`. The problem is, whereas the files:

```
$TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/my-package-⟨n⟩.sty
```

would be found by TeX, here the files:

```
$TEXMFHOME/my-package-⟨n⟩/tex/latex/my-package-⟨n⟩.sty
```

*aren't* found by TeX.

### Cloning repositories in `$TEXMFHOME/`: not a solution

Cloning these repositories directly into `TEXMFHOME`'s root is possible by running from `$TEXMFHOME/` directory e.g.:

```
git clone ssh://path/to/my-package-1.git .
```

Now the problem is that doing the same for the other repository isn't possible:

```
git clone ssh://path/to/my-package-2.git .
```

fails with:

```
fatal: destination path '.' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

### Cloning repositories in `$TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/my-package-⟨n⟩/`: a solution but probably not the best one

A workaround would be to run the commands:

```
git clone ssh://path/to/my-package-⟨n⟩.git
```

from ad hoc directories, e.g.

```
$TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/my-package-⟨n⟩/
```

This would give the following structures:

```
$TEXMFHOME
└── tex
    └── latex
        └── my-package-⟨n⟩
            ├── doc
            │   └── latex
            │       └── my-package-⟨n⟩
            │           ├── README
            │           ├── README.md
            │           └── my-package-⟨n⟩.pdf
            ├── source
            │   └── latex
            │       └── my-package-⟨n⟩
            │           ├── my-package-⟨n⟩.dtx
            │           └── my-package-⟨n⟩.ins
            └── tex
                └── latex
                    └── my-package
                        └── my-package-⟨n⟩.sty
```

and, indeed, the files:

```
$TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/my-package-⟨n⟩/tex/latex/my-package-⟨n⟩.sty
```

*are* found by TeX.

But I guess there are better strategies. Hence my question: what would be the strategies for providing packages as version control repositories?

---

¹ These question is asked with TeX Live distribution in mind but could be adapted to MiKTeX.

Comment: Are we allowed to suggest symlinks?

Comment: @JosephWright Why not? :)

Comment: You could provide a `Makefile` with a `installlocal` rule. People would `git clone` or later `pull`, and then rune `make installlocal`. (I do this with [xint](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint), admittedly there is no clonable repo, but the CTAN contains the suitable `Makefile`.) However, maybe your users are on various systems. A `zip` archive is also very convenient  `unzip foo.zip -d <TEXMF>`.

Comment: @jfbu I would like to avoid as many steps as possible and make all the necessary (compiled) files (`*.sty`, etc.) available with just one command (`git clone ...`). Moreover, some of the testers are Windows users, probably without `Cygwin` and hence `Makefile` could be painful to install. About `zip`: I would like to avoid this pain to me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest not trying to place the main repository into the local TeX tree but rather using appropriate symbolic links (available on Windows at least if one as Admin rights). For testing, the only part of your tree that needs to be visible to TeX is `tex`, not `source` or `doc` (though they could be added). Thus I would have a symbolic link between `[HOME]/my-package/tex/latex/my-package` and `$TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/mypackage`. Indeed, I'd probably simplify your structure to `[HOME]/my-package/latex/my-package`, *etc.* This will let you do testing on a 'live' version of your code whilst leaving your repository both flexible in terms of structure and placed somewhere more 'natural' for work than inside `TEXMFHOME` (for example inside some development directory in your main documents directory).

Comment: Note that whilst this is what I've got for `beamer`, that's mainly as I've inherited it from others: I personally prefer to use a script and to install the 'unpacked' version of my code as necessary.

Comment: I would let the `doc` part of the tree visible to TeX in order to increase the probability the testers will read the documentations (`texdoc my-package-⟨n⟩`) ;)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I'd hope people testing and checking out a Git version of your code will also spot that the repository itself has the documentation in it (or indeed it might not: it's a derived file so arguably should not be checked in).

Comment: Indeed, but less easy than just typing in a terminal `texdoc my-package-⟨n⟩` from any directory.

Answer (score 2):

I provided this uninstalled use for class `lettre` (see [lettre project](http://gna.org/projects/lettre_observatoire)).

You can get the version control (git) work-area of your project in any suitable directory and then add it to the list of TEXMF roots. See `lettre` manual, §« 1.2 Installation à partir des sources », and for item 3 of the enumerate list, select second bullet.

The cost of having  an « uninstalled » package/class is that you cannot recompile easily the manual when the work area has been added to the list of TEXMF roots, because then latex fails to find the source files in the current directory. In the case of `lettre` I worked around this issue by the makefile detecting this situation and relocating all the sources in a temp directory before compiling the manual.