# kpsewhich can't find symlinked paths under $TEXMFHOME/tex/lualatex/ (but finds those under $TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/)

Tags: luatex, texmf, kpsewhich

(This is a kind of followup of the nice [Joseph's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282463/18401) about [Strategies for providing packages as version control repositories](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/282457/18401).)

From `kpsewhich` point of view, symbolic links from:

- `$TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/...` works nicely
- `$TEXMFHOME/tex/lualatex/...` doesn't work.

Real example:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/dev/test-latex/tex/latex/test-latex/
$ touch    ~/dev/test-latex/tex/latex/test-latex/test-latex.cls
$ cd       ~/texmf/tex/latex
$ ln -s    ~/dev/test-latex/tex/latex/test-latex/
$ kpsewhich test-latex.cls
/home/bitouze/texmf/tex/latex/test-latex/test-latex.cls
$
$ mkdir -p ~/dev/test-lualatex/tex/lualatex/test-lualatex/
$ touch    ~/dev/test-lualatex/tex/lualatex/test-lualatex/test-lualatex.cls
$ cd       ~/texmf/tex/lualatex
$ ln -s    ~/dev/test-lualatex/tex/lualatex/test-lualatex/
$ kpsewhich test-lualatex.cls
$
$ # Cleanup
$ rm -rf   ~/dev/test-latex
$ rm -rf   ~/texmf/tex/latex/test-latex
$ rm -rf   ~/dev/test-lualatex
$ rm -rf   ~/texmf/tex/lualatex/test-lualatex
```

Hence, `kpsewhich`:

- finds `test-latex.cls`,
- doesn't find `test-lualatex.cls`.

Note that the previous symlinks were pointing to directories. If the symlinks created point to files, the problem doesn't arise (`kpsewhich` finds `test-lualatex.cls`):

```
$ mkdir -p ~/dev/test-lualatex/tex/lualatex/test-lualatex/
$ touch    ~/dev/test-lualatex/tex/lualatex/test-lualatex/test-lualatex.cls
$ mkdir    ~/texmf/tex/lualatex/test-lualatex
$ cd       ~/texmf/tex/lualatex/test-lualatex
$ ln -s    ~/dev/test-lualatex/tex/lualatex/test-lualatex/*
$ cd
$ kpsewhich test-lualatex.cls
/home/bitouze/texmf/tex/lualatex/test-lualatex/test-lualatex.cls
$
$ # Cleanup
$ rm -rf   ~/dev/test-lualatex
$ rm -rf   ~/texmf/tex/lualatex/test-lualatex
```

What's going on?

Comment: did you try `kpsewhich --progname=lualatex `?

Comment: By any chance is the directory which does not work populated exclusively with symlinks?

Comment: but beside this: I wouldn't use symlinks and similar, but tell people to clone whereever they want and then add the texmf with `tlmgr conf auxtrees add ...` (miktex has a similar command).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Got curious. Why would you say this is better? And, do the `auxtrees` get searched as `$TEXMFHOME`, or they need `texhash`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `kpsewhich --progname=lualatex` gives indeed the expected result. Strange symlinks to files instead of directories works without `--progname=lualatex`, though.

Comment: @gusbrs It is indeed populated exclusively with symlinks, but just as the `latex` one is.

Comment: @gusbrs because it is easy to use, works in windows and linux in the same way and without any admin rights.  And it doesn't polute my texmfhome. And yes one doesn't need texhash (unless you force it). I use it very often to attach and remove local trees.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I don't know why the `latex` one works, but try adding a real directory inside it (called whatever, say, `dummy`). For why, see https://www.tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html#Unable-to-find-files

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'll take a closer look at them. Thanks!

Comment: @gusbrs The latex one works since it's explicitly listed as a search directory (same as `lualatex` when progname=lualatex is set), while lualatex (without progname=lualatex) is not explicitly listed but only part of a general "look everywhere else" fallback. The symlink issue does not apply to directly listed directories.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger It was a guess. But you get better info. ;)